# Deponent verb participle gender

Tags: declension, participle, perfect-tense, deponent-verbs, agreement

If we consider a deponent verb such as *arbitrārī* in the perfect tense, hence *arbitrātus sum/es/est*, is the participle *arbitrātus* supposed to be declined like a regular adjective? For example if one wants to say

> Syra thought that Quintus was dead

is it

> Syra Quintum mortuum esse arbitrāt**us** est

or

> Syra Quintum mortuum esse arbitrāt**a** est

?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for a good first question! I look forward to seeing more questions from you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the second option with *arbitrata*.
For the purposes of agreement, you can think of the participle as an adjective, so that *Syra arbitrata est* and *Syra Romana est* have exactly the same form.

The gender agreement holds for all subjects of all numbers in the same way.
For example, *uxores arbitratae sunt* and *mariti arbitrati sunt*.
And there is no difference between passive perfect forms of normal transitive verbs and active perfect forms of deponent verbs.
Deponent verbs are not special in any way here.